# VB6 Store a Decimal Number

Tags: vb6

I am trying to do a calculation in a function to work out a percentage. However the percentage variable comes out as 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public FullLoopNum as Integer
Public ReportPercentage As Integer
Public ReportRecordNum As Integer

Public Function WebOutput

ReportRecordNum = 1
FullLoopNum = 4

ReportPercentage = (ReportRecordNum \ FullLoopNum)
ReportPercentage = ReportPercentage * 100



End Function
```

Comment: Integers are *whole* numbers... i.e. no decimal places.

Comment: Don't confuse yourself and others by using words like "decimal" when that isn't what you mean.  What you want to work with are *real* numbers and you normally approximate these to work with them using `Single` or `Double` types.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Double type and change the division operator to a forward slash.

```
Public FullLoopNum as Integer
Public ReportPercentage As Double
Public ReportRecordNum As Integer

ReportPercentage = (ReportRecordNum * 100 / FullLoopNum)
```

Comment: You cannot declare a variable as `Decimal` in VB6, unfortunately.

Comment: Working too much in SQL recently.  Should have specified Double.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using only Integers, which are non floating point (whole) numbers. You are going to need a combination of `Variant` datatype and the `CDec` function. Something like this:

```
Public FullLoopNum as Variant
Public ReportPercentage As Variant
Public ReportRecordNum As Variant

ReportPercentage = CDec(ReportRecordNum / FullLoopNum)
ReportPercentage = CDec(ReportPercentage * 100)
```

I have not tested this, but it should give you an idea on how to proceed using `CDec`.  Alternatively, you could use the `Currency` datatype.

Comment: I would clarify to strongly use the `Currency` data-type.  That way, you don't need to use `Variant`s.  And the `Decimal` data-type is a bit massive.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2, yes, I agree.

Comment: It seems to be rounding the number. I am supposed to be getting the number 1.25 but it outputs 1. Would the currency data type work as this is not for a currency?

Comment: @AlexHarvey, I would have to see the input. You have to CDec the input as well, so that it's in the variable as a floating point number there too.

Comment: The problem is that you're using the slash instead of the forward slash for your operator.

Comment: @SilentD I have no idea why I did that. Thank you... The evils of copy and paste!